# ggplot background image across (geo)facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-image, facet-grid

I want to add an actual map of Europe in the background of the graph on the left:
[image]

The code for the original graph is taken from [here](https://github.com/jack-davison/TidyTuesday/blob/master/R/2020_08_04_European_Energy.R) (producing [this graph at "03/08/2020  European Power"](https://github.com/jack-davison/TidyTuesday#03082020--european-power-code)) and there is a slightly shorter version with my suggested solution that does not work as intended at the end of this post. In short, my suggestion is this:

**Step 1:** Get the image

```r
img_path <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Blank_map_of_Europe_cropped.svg/1000px-Blank_map_of_Europe_cropped.svg.png"
img <- readPNG(img_path)
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate = FALSE)
```

**Step 2:** Add image to ggplot-background as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333085/how-to-fit-the-plot-over-a-background-image-in-r-and-ggplot2)

```r
annotation_custom(g, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)
```

But it does not do the job. Anybody know a solution to this?

**EDIT:** For clarity, once the map is there, I don't want to further adjust the grid so that each group of bars exactly matches the location of a country. I really only want to replace the dark background on the left with the map on the right.

#### Full example code

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, tidytuesdayR, geofacet, grid, png)

## import image
img_path <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Blank_map_of_Europe_cropped.svg/1000px-Blank_map_of_Europe_cropped.svg.png"
img <- readPNG(img_path)
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate = FALSE)

## Load in data
tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load('2020-08-04')

## Match countries in data w/ grid, do some pivoting
energy_raw <- tuesdata$energy_types %>%
  mutate(country_name = case_when(country_name == "North Macedonia" ~ "N. Macedonia",
                                  country_name == "Bosnia & Herzegovina" ~ "Bosnia & H.",
                                  country == "UK" ~ "UK",
                                  country == "EL" ~ "Greece",
                                  TRUE ~ country_name)) %>%
  filter(country_name %in% europe_countries_grid2$name) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`2016`,`2017`,`2018`), names_to = "year") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-country)

## Work out percentages of the total and tidy the data
energy_plot <- left_join(energy_raw %>% filter(level == "Level 1") %>% select(-level) %>% janitor::remove_empty("cols"),
                         energy_raw %>% filter(level == "Level 2") %>% select(-level) %>% janitor::remove_empty("cols")) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(tot = sum(conventional_thermal, nuclear, hydro, wind, solar, geothermal, other, pumped_hydro_power),
         across(where(is.numeric), ~ 100 * . / tot)) %>%
  select(-tot) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "energy", values_to = "value", 
               c(conventional_thermal, nuclear, hydro, wind, solar, geothermal, other, pumped_hydro_power)) %>%
  rbind(expand.grid(country_name = setdiff(europe_countries_grid2$name, energy_raw$country_name),
                    year = 2016:2018, energy = "No Data Available", value = 100)) %>%
  mutate(energy = case_when(energy == "conventional_thermal" ~ "Conventional Thermal",
                            energy == "nuclear" ~ "Nuclear",
                            energy == "No Data Available" ~ energy,
                            TRUE ~ "Renewable"),
         energy = factor(energy, 
                         levels = c("Conventional Thermal", "Nuclear", 
                                    "Renewable", "No Data Available"))) %>%
  group_by(energy, year, country_name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% mutate(country_name = str_trunc(country_name, 11))

## Plot!

ggplot(energy_plot) +
  
  # background image
  annotation_custom(g, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) + 
  
  # The actual proper plotting stuff here isn't actually that complicated!
  aes(x = year, y = value, fill = energy) +
  geom_col(color = "#30332E") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  
  # facet_geo from the "geofacet" package - I truncate the names here just to be sure
  facet_geo( ~ country_name,
             grid = europe_countries_grid2 %>% mutate(name = str_trunc(name, 11))) +
  
  # colours and themes
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EF476F", "#FFD166", "#06D6A0", "#4B5446")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1.2), "cm"),
    legend.position = c(0.075, .125)
  )
```